# Single Linked List in reverse order Java

Tags: java

How to write a code for printing Single linked list in reverse order?

```
private class Elem {

    private int data;
    private Elem next;

    public Elem(int data, Elem next) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = next;

    }

    public Elem(int data) {
        this(data, null);
    }
}
private Elem first = null, last = null;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to reverse a linked list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076923/how-to-reverse-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can write a recursive method:

```
public static void printReversed (Elem start)
{
    if (start.next != null) {
        printReversed(start.next); // print the rest of the list in reversed order
    }
    System.out.println(start.data); // print the first element at the end
}
```

Comment: This is a standard solution to the problem but let's put some light over it though: `1. Check if there is another element in the list and if so process it first.`, `2. Process current element afterwards.`.