# Rearranging a linked list into a spiral linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list

I was trying to solve a linked list question in which we have to rearrange the linked list in a spiral fashion i.e starting from the center and move towards the end, picking a node from the left side then the right side from the center.
For better understanding I have an example:
Consider the input as:

`Input: 1->2->3->4->5->6->7`

The center element here is 4 (7/2 = 3rd element). Hence it becomes the new head and then the next element comes from the left of 4 that was3, and the next element from it's right which is 5. And so on the final list that we get is:

`Output: 4->3->5->2->6->1->7`

Can you guys help me in solving this!(Also the expected space complexity is O(1) (as pointed out by @trincot in the comments).

Comment: NB: Are you sure you are allowed to use a stack? I mean, if that is allowed, why not dump the whole list into an array, perform the logic there (which is much simpler) and the convert it back to linked list. These type of challenges often require you to *only* use a linked list (and a constant number of node references).

Comment: BTW, you should really stick to one question, either finding the mistake, or finding a more efficient solution.

Comment: Oh actually it's my first post so I just wrote everything, but I will surely edit it now.

Comment: It doesn't seem you've given any insight as to how *you're* approaching the problem yet, so it's a bit hard to give a push in the right direction. For the first hint, observe that a true O(1) space solution would require destroying the original linked list. As a second hint, observe that it's possible to determine the center element given your constraints. As a third hint, we can cleverly modify the nodes to the left of the center in a way where we simulate the use of a stack by modifying their pointers. You should be able to draw out an example and algorithm from here.

Comment: Generally speaking, we prefer to see that you have attempted a solution, and we prefer to give you advice about your attempt, rather than to provide details of a full solution.  That is, the question was better before the edit.

Comment: Oh thanks for the tip. I would take care of this the next time as currently I am really confused if I should put the code back because I think the way I approached it was totally wrong, i.e using other data structures - stack and queue when the question demands it to be solved using linked list only.

Comment: @KunalChaudhary, it is true that you do not need any additional data structures to solve this problem. wLui155 gave you some good hints about how you could do without.  Here are few additional ones: (a) it is possible to reverse a linked list without using a stack, simply by changing the links.  This can be done with O(1) space overhead.  (b) It is possible to find the midpoint of a singly-linked list with O(1) space overhead, and you can probably Google that if you can't figure out how. (c) A queue doesn't gain you anything you need that a linked list does not also provide.

Answer (score 0):

This is much easier if you have a doubly-linked list. Even if you have a singly-linked list, first convert it into doubly-linked list then it becomes easy.

It will be as follows:

a) Start with center node - easy to get the center node - by having two moving pointers one from the tail node and other from the head node and their meeting point is the center node.

b) We will have available 'left' and 'right' nodes - because moving in a spiral is actually nothing but alternating between left and right directions.
and as long as you have available left and right nodes you keep changing direction and build a linked list.

The general logic would be :

```
function get_spiral_ll()
    current_node = center_node
    new_head = current_node
    next_available_left_node = current_node->prev
    next_available_right_node = null
    direction = 'left'
    while(next_available_left_node != null ||
           next_available_right_node != null)
       if direction == 'left' && next_available_left_node != null
           next_available_right_node = current_node->next
           current_node->next = next_available_left_node
           current_node = next_available_left_node
           direction = 'right'
       else if direction == 'right' && next_available_right_node != null
           next_available_left_node = current_node->prev
           current_node->next = next_available_right_node
           current_node = next_available_right_node
           direction = 'left'
       else
          break

    return new_head
```

- Without Doubly linked list:

You can do without doubly linked list although not very straighforward in this way for the example

```
1 -> 2 -> 3 -> 4 -> 5 -> 6 -> 7
```

a) Reverse the linked list from head to center node ( `1 - 4` ) - its straightforward. Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9076923/how-can-i-reverse-a-linked-list)

b) Then you get `4 -> 3 -> 2 -> 1`
Then starting at 3, insert nodes 5, 6, 7 in between the nodes. Then you get

```
4 -> 3 -> 5 -> 2 -> 6 -> 1 -> 7
```

Comment: By converting a singly list to a double list, you introduce O(n) auxiliary space. It can be done without that.